# Rails validates_presence_of is checking against saved record instead of edited record

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have three models model1, model12 and mode2. Model1 has many model2 through model 12.

I have to validated presence of model2 through model12.

When I try to save edited record for model1 rails is saving the record which doesn't have model2 with it. Validation only fails when already present DB entry in model1 doesn't have model2 information.

```
class model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model12, :dependent => :destroy, :include => [:model]
  has_many :model2, :through => :model12, :uniq => true

  validates_presence_of :model12, :message => "must be present"
```

I tried

```
  validates_presence_of :model2, :message => "must be present"
```

This is also not working.

I guess in my case somehow rails is checking saved record instead of unsaved record.
That's why when already saved record has model2 and unsaved record doesn't have model2 validation doesn't fails. But it fails when saved record doesn't have model2 and unsaved record also doesn't have model2.

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: I think you should add a custom validation for this.

Comment: @SanthoshK I was doing that like

validate do |model1|
  model1.error("must be selected") if model1.model12s.blank?
end

But here also same prob this "if model1.model12s" is returning old value which is in DB.

Comment: This works for me.  validate :address_present
  def address_present
    self.errors.add(:name, "can't be blank") if self.addresses.size == 0
  end

Comment: What about : validates :model12_ids, :length => { :minimum => 1 } ? It works for me, but with a has_and_belongs_to_many association. But It's pretty much the same I guess.

Comment: @SanthoshK Thanks for you commit I tried. That also doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: @Saaman Thanks for the comment. I tried that also. :( Doesn't work for me.

Comment: @SanthoshK I found the solution. Please check my answer. I'm sure you would be happy to see the answer. :)

Comment: @Saaman I found the solution. Please check my answer. I'm sure you would be happy to see the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

I had model2s in check-boxes. When I was unchecking all checked model2s and submitting the form. Because I was using nested attributes it was marking old unchecked model2s for destruction and this destruction will happen after save and validation runs before that.

so rails was finding some model2s present so no validation errors.

```
class model1 < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :model12, :dependent => :destroy, :include => [:model]
  has_many :model2, :through => :model12, :uniq => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :model2,
    :allow_destroy => true,
    :reject_if => proc {|m| m.blank? }

  validate :must_have_one_model2

  def must_have_one_model2
    errors.add(:model2s, 'must have one model2') if model12s_count_valid?
  end

  def model12s_count_valid?
    model12s.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).count >= 1
  end
end
```

Thanks to les hill's post [validation presence with nested models](http://blog.leshill.org/blog/2010/04/20/validating-presence-with-nested-models.html)